# Multiple netconnection at one mxml application?

Tags: apache-flex, netconnection

Since I have to get data from other red5 application. is it possible using multiple netconnection in one mxml application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible yo use multiple netConnection.

But also if you need to connect to just one application you can use just ine netConnection and 
multiple responser for each call diifferent.